# Move rest of website down when opening collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I am creating a website with a hamburger menu. 
The submenu is expanded when clicking a button. Everything is working the way it should but when I expand the submenus the rest of the menu doesn't move down and things start to overlap.
I want that if you expand the submenu, the rest of the menu moves down. 
How do I accomplish this? 
I reduced the problem to the minimum in this jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/8nsuhjav/

Keep in mind that at the bottom of the jsfiddle is the following script:

```
    <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("expandsubmenu");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Problem is with your CSS not javascript.

Comment: Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/ugLtj7p6/2/)?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Do I have to use different position properties?

Comment: yes skobaljic. What did I do wrong? I would really like to understand what I did wrong...

Comment: If you put expanding list absolute position, than it will be removed from the flow, which means other content won't move. Talking about the `.menulist`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS with is partly because of the way your HTML is structured. The two `div`'s you have before opening the `body` tag is not necessary, I will suggest you put them within the body (if you really want them in your code).
on the other hand, you have `li` but no parent `ul` HTML5 is forgiving i get it, but why not change th `div` with class `mobilemenuitems` to `ul` then do something like this:

```
  <div id="BurgerSpace">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="mobilemenuspace">
      <ul class="mobilemenuitems">
        <li>
          <a href="?module=start">CLUB</a>
          <button class="expandsubmenu">
            <div class="circle-plus closed">
              <div class="circle">
                <div class="horizontal"></div>
                <div class="vertical"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Ueber-Uns">�ber uns</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Mitgliedsantrag"
                >Mitgliedschaft</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Vorstand">Vorstand</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Gastronomie">Gastronomie</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*Partner">Partner</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*Hockey">HOCKEY</a>
          <button class="expandsubmenu">
            <div class="circle-plus closed">
              <div class="circle">
                <div class="horizontal"></div>
                <div class="vertical"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1-Herren">1. Herren</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1-Damen">1. Damen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Erwachsene">Erwachsene</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#"
                >Jugend <span class="fa arrow"></span
              ></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Jugend">Jugend</a>
                </li>

                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mja">M�nnliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mjb">M�nnliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*kna">A-Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*knb">B-Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*knc">C-Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*knd">D-Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*kne">E-Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*wja">Weibliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*wjb">Weibliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*maa">A-M�dchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mab">B-M�dchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mac">C-M�dchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mad">D-M�dchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*mae">E-M�dchen</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Plan">Trainingsplan</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Schiedsrichter"
                >Schiedsrichter</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Links">Offizielle Links</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Kalender">Kalender</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS like:

```
.mobilemenuitems,
.menulist {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.expandsubmenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
}
```

it will be working the way you expect it you just have to add more styles to make it visually appealing. 
NB - when you use `position: any-valid-value` the element will be removed from its natural context by the browser so there might be an overlap of elements if you do not put that into consideration.

PS - nesting `ul` with an `li` element is valid HTML.